# Ajax button doesn't work

Tags: 7, hooks, ajax

I followed this tutorial:
https://rapiddg.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-user-reference-fields

to create a button to fill some field in a form with the values of the current user.

Here the cose I added to my hoo_form_alter:

```
if ($form_id == 'datore_node_form')
{
global $user;
  $form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden';
  $form['title']['#value'] = 'test';

$form['user_replace'] = array(
    '#title' => t("User Information"),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="datore_node_form_group_cs">',
    //name of the node form (already existing, if you're modifying an existing node form)
    '#suffix' =>'</div>',

    $form['user_replace']['user_copy'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => 'Sono io il datore!',
      '#ajax' => array(
        'event'=>'click',
        'callback' =>'user_replace_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'datore_node_form_group_cs',
      ),
    ),
  );

 $form['user_replace']['field_cognome'] = $form['field_cognome'];
  unset($form['field_cognome']);

  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  dpm($user);
  dpm($user->field_cognome['und'][0]['value']);
  dpm($form);
  dpm($form_state);

  if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_cognome']))
  {
    unset($form_state['input']['field_cognome']['und'][0]['value']);
    $form_state['input']['field_cognome']['und'][0]['value'] = $user->field_cognome['und'][0]['value'];
    return $form;
  }

  function user_replace_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state)
  {
    ajax_command_alert("hello"); // doesn't work
    return $form['user_replace'];
  }
```

but if I click the button nothing happen.
Any advise?

Comment: I can't really follow whats going on here, but if you are creating ajax commands you have to return a different response than the form item. You have to return an array of commands as `type => '#ajax'`

Comment: Could you kindly provide an example?

Comment: First, get rid of all the `dpm()` calls. It will make debugging tougher for AJAX calls. Look into using xdebug. But in order to use ajax commands, your callback has to return an array of commands as an `#ajax` response type. See the callback function in this example: http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-your-own-custom-drupal-7-ajax-framework-command or the ajax callback here https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/calling-function-after-ajax-event-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are doing with your code is replacing the button that you are clicking. It's probably getting replaced, but visually will look exactly the same as it did before, which is why it appears nothing is happening.

Comment: OK, but under "['user_replace']" I have this:
$form['user_replace']['field_cognome'], so the field I suppose should be filled, isn't it?

Comment: It's there on the initial load, it should be there on the ajax submit as well. You'll need to update your code to show where $form['field_cognome'] comes from to be able to understand.

Comment: $form['field_cognome'] comes from the original form I created with the UI

Comment: Looks like it should be the same either way to me. Open up a JS console, and examine the response to see if you are actually getting a response. Also, note that your alert will never happen, as another poster mentioned.

Comment: Also see Jaypans own post here for how to use AJAX commands in a callback https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/calling-function-after-ajax-event-drupal-7

Comment: @Jaypan: how can I examine the response on Firefox tools?

Comment: Open the network tab. Scroll to the bottom. Click the ajax button, and you'll see a new post request. Click on that and examine the response.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/3q28x2cr3/
a lot of staff but nothing related at the value I need. Should show here the value of `$user->field_cognome['und'][0]['value'];` right?

Comment: Try changing your button from type button to type submit.

Comment: Actually I was able using "Simplest AJAX Example" to update one field.
My problem now is that I need to update a series of fields under a fieldgroup div, but adding '#prefix' and '#suffix' to the fieldgroup doesn't work (fieldgroups are objects and not array).
if I render all the form, all is working except I lost the css of the custom css.
What's wrong?